# UnassignedReferenceException : The variable player of FollowPlayer has not being assigned

Tags: unity, c#

My current task is to make the camera follow the moving cube in a stable way where the camera won't get locked in the center of the object so it won't get dizzy once the cube starts to collide or fall down.

I have done the parenting right, I have named the cube as the player and then selected it as the Transform reference in the new component that I have created for the camera to follow.

But it just says:

> UnassignedReferenceException : The variable player of FollowPlayer has not being assigned.

and I am unable to get the right results. What should I do ?

Here is the C# script that I wrote:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void Update() {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }
}
```

My scene setup looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Unity editor showing "Player" variable correctly assigned]

So I have un-parented the main camera from the player and it works perfectly fine but I still get the error, Have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have a stray second instance of your `FollowPlayer` script somewhere in your scene, with its `player` variable unset.

You can have every instance print its name to the debug console in `Start()` to help track it down.

If the camera's reference to the `Player` transform was deleted or cleared, you'd get a MissingReferenceException or NullReferenceException instead, so this is almost certainly a scene & inspector setup issue.

Comment: 3 years later someone finally upvotes your answer 

Comment: ...and 9 community bumps... :P